# How can I figure out channel number of a Nifti file in python?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, nibabel

I work on deep learning with medical images and use nibabel package for reading .nii files in python. My code is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import nibabel as nib

img_path=r"C:\\Users\\Umit Kilic\\Komodomyfiles\\umit\\myfile.nii"

nii_obj=nib.load(img_path)
img=nii_obj.get_fdata()
slice1=(img[60,:,:])
slice2=(img[:,80,:])
slice3=(img[:,:,60])
```

Then I select a slice and want to see in the figure.

```
figure()
imshow(slice2)
show()
```

The output of the above code snippet is this: [image: Output of code]

After that, I want to apply some operation such as:

```
 slice2[:, :, 0] -= 123.68
 slice2[:, :, 1] -= 116.779
 slice2[:, :, 2] -= 103.939
```

But I can not. Cause when I run that code:

```
print(slice2.shape)
```

The output is

## (121,121)

Normally there should be a third parameter that says the number of channels. There are two parameters. So, is my slice2 grayscale or RGB? How can I apply the operation that I mentioned above?

Comment: Why should the `shape` of `slice2` be different? You are modifying the `img` array by changing its content, not its dimension. In the definition of `slice2`, you are dropping one of the dimensions, so of course it's 2 dimensional. By the way, after you modify `img`, you have to again run `slice2 = (img[:,80,:])`, because every time you slice an array, the values are copied.

Comment: @darksky the code starts with img[:,:,0]-=123.68 belongs to another code. I want to do same opeartion. For avoiding misunderstanding, I changed the code with slice2[] instead of img[]. I want to subtract related value from related channel of slices2 as in the code snipped.

Comment: @darksky when I added img[:,:,:,0]-=123.60 code, this error is shown: IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: Are you trying to convert RGB to BGR? I'm looking at https://github.com/KaimingHe/deep-residual-networks/issues/5, does that code snippet help you?

Comment: @darksky I want to subtract the values from RGB channels, but probably it is not RGB and that's why I can not.

Comment: that's a good point, and is entirely possible. Can you share your `myfile.nii` so that I can test it?